# Building and Installing ICU from Source

Tags: compiling, make, unicode

The setup process for ICU on Linux systems seems to be pretty standard. For whatever reason, though, it's giving me a hard time. I'm following the "official" readme instructions that come with the download, but they can also be found here: http://orot-technologies.com/readme.html. I'm not having any problems with the actual build/installation perse, but I am unable to build my own projects or any of the samples. Mind you, these all worked in Windows. Initially, I was getting "undefined reference" errors like:

```
> /home/luke/workspace/test2/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:19: undefined
> reference to `icu_54::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const*)
```

Then, I tried adding ".../icu/source/lib" as a library, which merely upgrades me to this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/luke/Documents/icu/icu/source/lib
```

For the record, this is the code I am trying to execute:

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    UnicodeString test("test");

    return 0;
}
```

The header is found.

I would prefer to build the library from source.